# \n appending at the end of each line

Tags: python

I am writing lines one by one to an external files. Each line has 9 columns separated by Tab delimiter. If i split each line in that file and output last column, i can see \n being appended to the end of the 9 column. My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("temp", "r") as f:
    for lines in f:
        hashes = lines.split("\t")
        print hashes[8]
```

The last column values are integers, either 1 or 2. When i run this program, the output i get is,

```
['1\n']
['2\n']
```

I should only get 1 or 2. Why is '\n' being appended here?

I tried the following check to remove the problem.

```
with open("temp", "r") as f:
    for lines in f:
            if lines != '\n':
                    hashes = lines.split("\t")
                    print hashes[8]
```

This too is not working. I tried `if lines != ' '`. How can i make this go away? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each line has 9 columns, the 8th index (which is the 9th object) has a line break, since the next line starts. Just take that away:

```
print hashes[8][:-1]
```

Comment: That would modify some of the columnar data. `'\n'` is a single character. So `hashes[8][:-1]` is what I think you're after

Answer (score 7):

Try using [strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) on the lines to remove the `\n` (the new line character). `strip` removes the leading and trailing whitespace characters.

```
with open("temp", "r") as f:
    for lines in f.readlines():
        if lines.strip():
            hashes = lines.split("\t")
            print hashes[8]
```

Answer (score 3):

\n is the newline character, it is how the computer knows to display the data on the next line.  If you modify the last item in the array hashes[-1] to remove the last character, then that should be fine.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining what's going on, but you should mention the `strip` function as well.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the platform, your line ending may be more than just one character. Dos/Windows uses `"\r\n"` for example.

```
def clean(file_handle):
    for line in file_handle:
        yield line.rstrip()

with open('temp', 'r') as f:
    for line in clean(f):
        hashes = line.split('\t')
        print hashes[-1]
```

I prefer `rstrip()` for times when I want to preserve leading whitespace. That and using generator functions to clean up my input.